# mysql Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, locking

```
mysql Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction ...
```

Why need to restart transaction?

For example.

```
select * from Foo for update
```

It should be statement-level rollback. The transaction should not be rolled back since the statement did nothing to the transaction.

Comment: *The transaction should not be rolled back since the statement did nothing to the transaction.* In general any statement within the transaction MAY affect - so if any statement fails the whole transaction is rolled back. Server will not distinguish your particular case...

Comment: any example that can affect current transaction if lock timeout?